# Indexing flaw, changing color of Vertices

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Keep making same mistake.

Horizontal lines is always result. Trying to display random points.

```
import cv2 as cv, numpy as np, random
blank = np.ones((300,300), np.uint8) * 255

X, Y = [], []

for i in np.arange(1,300,1):
    X.append(random.randrange(1,300))
for i in np.arange(1,300,1):
    Y.append(random.randrange(1,300))

XY = np.column_stack((np.asarray(X),np.asarray(Y)))

# change values of Vertex index to black. 
blank[XY] = 1

cv.imshow('', blank)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Random array of pixels is intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is okay in your code, just require some change which is that we have to pass `X, Y` instead of `XY`.

```
blank[X, Y] = 1
```

So basically index operater `[]` requires a tuple so we can create our own using `XY`.

```
# tuple(XY.transpose())
blank[tuple(XY.transpose())] = 1
```

---

```
import cv2 as cv, numpy as np, random
blank = np.ones((300,300), np.uint8) * 255

X, Y = [], []

for i in np.arange(1,300,1):
    X.append(random.randrange(1,300))
for i in np.arange(1,300,1):
    Y.append(random.randrange(1,300))

# XY = np.column_stack((np.asarray(X),np.asarray(Y)))

# change values of Vertex index to black. 
blank[X, Y] = 1

cv.imshow('', blank)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: How about if they're already V-stacked?

Comment: but still u have to have to pass then in fromat of tuple, `XY = np.vstack((np.asarray(X),np.asarray(Y)))` and then `blank[tuple(XY)] = 1`

Comment: which is the same thing i am doing in second method `blank[tuple(XY.transpose())] = 1`